# FBX not importing with shape keys that should be present

Tags: import, unity, shape-keys

I've been using an FBX in Unity and recently I wanted to tweak the BlendShapes/shape keys on the face so I imported into Blender 3.1.1 and the shape keys section is empty.

Here's what the editor looks like in unity after dropping the FBX into the scene. It shows that BlendShapes are present on the FBX

[image: Photo showing BlendShapes in unity editor]

However when importing into blender using the FBX import option, it looks like the shape keys are not imported

[image: Photo showing shape keys being empty in Blender]

For context here's me importing a different model that also has blend shapes but importing the mesh includes the shape keys, so not sure if it's some kind of bug or not.

[image: Image of a different model imported with the proper shape keys]

Anyone have any idea why this might be the case, if there's any way to fix it, and/or if I'm just stuck having to remake the shape keys since I don't have the original file to export it again.

Edit: Additional context, I forgot about the console, not sure if it's related but I checked the console while importing and got this and maybe it's possible it's related? I Don't get the "'Short' is not supported" message on the other model that imports correctly

```
FBX version: 7100
Error, could not find any file path in  FBXElem(id=b'Texture', props=[2611063097552, b'pasted__Map51\x00\x01Texture', b''], props_type=bytearray(b'LSS'), elems=[FBXElem(id=b'Type', props=[b'TextureVideoClip'], props_type=bytearray(b'S'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'Version', props=[202], props_type=bytearray(b'I'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'TextureName', props=[b'pasted__Map51\x00\x01Texture'], props_type=bytearray(b'S'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'Properties70', props=[], props_type=bytearray(b''), elems=[FBXElem(id=b'P', props=[b'CurrentTextureBlendMode', b'enum', b'', b'', 0], props_type=bytearray(b'SSSSI'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'P', props=[b'UVSet', b'KString', b'', b'', b'map1'], props_type=bytearray(b'SSSSS'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'P', props=[b'UseMaterial', b'bool', b'', b'', 1], props_type=bytearray(b'SSSSI'), elems=[])]), FBXElem(id=b'Media', props=[b''], props_type=bytearray(b'S'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'FileName', props=[b''], props_type=bytearray(b'S'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'RelativeFilename', props=[b''], props_type=bytearray(b'S'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'ModelUVTranslation', props=[0.0, 0.0], props_type=bytearray(b'DD'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'ModelUVScaling', props=[1.0, 1.0], props_type=bytearray(b'DD'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'Texture_Alpha_Source', props=[b'None'], props_type=bytearray(b'S'), elems=[]), FBXElem(id=b'Cropping', props=[0, 0, 0, 0], props_type=bytearray(b'IIII'), elems=[])])
       Falling back to:  pasted__Map51
WARNING: User property type 'Short' is not supported
WARNING: User property type 'Short' is not supported
WARNING: User property type 'Short' is not supported
WARNING: User property type 'Short' is not supported
```

Comment: use better FBX, it was better than normal fbx exporter